# How to checkout a github repo outside of git.workspace?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a requirement where I have to check out the github repository outside(/var/lib/builder) of the default github workspace i.e git.workspace . How to do that?

Also, when I am trying to copy a file from the git.workspace to some other directory, **Permission denied** error is coming.
The user under which the github actions is running has full admin permission. Still the error exists.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be available yet. There are some ISSUES about this subject on the proper [actions/checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/197).